# Fit and center div with containing image [CSS]

Tags: html, css

I made the following image to show my problem. Which CSS can I use to implement it?

[image]

For sure, i meant padding instead of margin of .page around the .image container...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried it via Jquery, position the imagecontainer absolutely over the <img>, but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to show us what you tried in the question itself so we can know what went wrong. Post the relevant code please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.page {
  distplay: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.page .imagecontainer {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you :)

```
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.imagecontainer {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: .imagecontainer should have the same aspect ratio as the image